# Cannot drop aws athena table across database

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I had created my test database, named: `test`, there was a table named: `test_table`

I executed the command from `default` database:
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.test_table` and got the error message:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
NoSuchObjectException(message:Table test_table not found. (Service: AmazonDataCatalog; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx))
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Are you doing this via the Athena Management Console, or via a JDBC connection? You say that you executed it from the `default` database -- have you tried it from the `test` database?

Comment: I executed the command via Console and JDBC, both ways were not workable. And if I executed the command from `test` database, it worked well. I just wondered why it didn't work via `default` database

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below steps and see whether you can delete it from the console:

1. From the amazon athena console, select catalog manager from the top bar
2. Select test database from the databases listed on the left hand side.
3. Select test_table listed in the tables section
4. Click on the drop option shown above the tables section

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just wondered why it didn't work via `default` database.